# Graph for lower and upperside bound absolute value function

Tags: functions, special-functions, graphing-functions

The relation to be represented in graph is as follows

$$ y = k \text{ for } k-1 < |x| < k \text{ where } k\in \mathbb Z  $$

Normally we plot the area where the relation holds good is where the graphs overlap ,
But here they don't seem to overlap. So I don't know how to plot the graph ?

I tried it in wolfram alpha to see how the graphs |x| > k-1 and |x| < k look separately and from which the overlapping area is where the entire relation holds good (I assumed k=2 for plotting)
[image]  for |x|<2

[image]  for |x| >1

One graphs area is outside the |x| boundary and other area is within it . How can the area overlap , how can I plot the relation in graph for the combined relation which I gave in line 2 of this question .

But the answer for this relation was given in a book as following

[image]

May I know how they arrived at this solution . Please correct me where I am going wrong in my understanding .

Thanks

Comment: Well, I believe that 'plotting a graph' doesn't mean plotting the area under the graph. It just means plotting those points $(x, y)$ that satisfy the relation.

Comment: But I believe plotting a graph for a relation means having graph where the relation holds good .

Comment: Exactly. It doesn't mean plotting the *area* under the graph. The graph holds only for a certain set of points. That's what the textbook graph shows. Your graph shows all the points under the curve. Think like this: if any point is marked on the graph, it must satisfy the graph's relation. The graphs you got from WA show some region marked. Do all the points in that region (e.g., say $(\sqrt2, \sqrt2)$ satisfy the relation $y = k$ where $k$ is an integer?

Comment: Also, basically the function whose graph you are seeking is the modulus of the greatest integer function (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_integer_function)

Comment: Ya I am getting your point .But if we satisfy y=k alone would that not violate |X| < 1 ?

Comment: That's why I am asking why the graph seems like not satisfying  entire relation

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9680/discussion-between-parth-thakkar-and-harish-kayarohanam)